# Visual Studio 2013-LINK : error LNK1181: cannot open input file “ \src-2015\..\LibSL-bin-win32\lib\LibSL.lib"”

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build

I'm new for programming with Visual studio 2013, and I created a project (a game) and created an installer using Cmake.

But when I build my project I get the following error:

and I had the following error when I try to build my project:

> Error  1   error LNK1181: cannot open input file '\src-2015..\LibSL-bin-win32\lib\LibSL.lib"'

the file '*.lib' is present I ckeck that, and there some posts in this website too but I tried them but they are not working? can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Your title and question text list different names for the file; which is it? I'm pretty sure `*` is not allowed in Windows file names, and am not sure what that character is in the title, so this could be important.

Comment: The name is :"\src-2015\..\LibSL-bin-win32\lib\LibSL.lib" and I used that to just specify the extencsion of the file

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit. You can not add a 32 bit lib to a 64 bit application and you can not add a 64 bit lib to a 32 bit application.

Comment: my project is 32 bit so this not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be an issue with properties, go to project properties, Linker, and somewhere in general there should be an option to set link library dependecies to no

Comment: Thanks for the replay, link liberary dependencies is set to $no$ and the liberary dependency input also